# Kenmore Dishwasher Leaking

Tags: leak, dishwasher

I have a Kenmore 665.13549N412 dishwasher. It seems to be leaking during the dry cycle only out of the left corner if you are facing the dishwasher with the door closed.

I have replaced the inner door gasket just to make sure thats not bad. The old one looked fine. The dishwasher is about 3 years old.

The water that is leaked is clear. I can reach up under the dishwasher to the sound deadening fabric just inside the lip at the bottom of the front door and can feel that it is wet. I am not sure where the water is coming from. Its not a large puddle, but its enough to be noticed.

Any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This will be tough to help remotely, but picture of the undercarriage of the dishwasher might help.  And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Any chance that it's an early indication of water pump shaft seal failure and that the water is following a wire or tubing to the place where the puddle appears?  Does this unit have an air gap, usually mounted on the outside of the tub, that might be backing up due to an obstructed pipe?

Comment: Doesnt appear to be. If I feel up underneath the washer and take the front beauty cover off there isnt any indication of a leak under the unit. The water on the floor is clear and its only the left corner. This indicates to me that it cant be a crooked door or the door latch otherwise I think both sides of the door would leak.

Comment: @telston, did you ever figure our the issue here?